# Call Passport API endpoint protected by passport-twitter strategy from Postman

Tags: postman, passport.js, passport-twitter

Currently I have an endpoint http://127.0.0.1/login/twitter that if I hit the Twitter Authentication pops up, I authorize, then the page itself works as expect.  I can then in the browser go to the endpoint of another page http;//127.0.0.1/api/tweets and see the expected result.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to authorize Postman Application to be able to first go to my login/twitter route and log in then be able to go to the /api/tweets route.  If I do it, the html for the twitter authorization from oauth shows up in the Pretty Results and the preview doesn't let me login.

How can I log into via passport on postman to be able to hit my endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should use NTLM authentication

[image]

Workstation is your computer hostname and domain is your domain used for windows authetication you can see it in internet explore when authentication pop up comes up

In username passord fields provide the credential you use for login to system

If this doesn't work try basic authentication, also you can inspect bthe network traffic in browser and see what authentication it uses when it successfully routes and use that specific auth in postman